# Find the transformation matrix of this transformation:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Find the transformation matrix:  $$F: \mathbb R_3[x]\  \mathbb
>  ] \to \mathbb R_3[x] $$ $$F(v) = \frac{d^2
>  v}{dv^2}$$ Basis: $1, x, x^2, x^3$ and $\mathbb R_3[x]$ - the set of
>    all third degree polynomials of variable $x$ over $\mathbb R$ Assume that all coefficients of the polynomials are $1$

The first thing that springs to my mind is to calculate this derivative by hand, and so we got $$\frac{d^2y}{dy^2}=2+6x$$
Now, we need to put these values - $2$ and $6$ in such a matrix that - when multiplied by the basis vector -will give us $2+6x$
But there are many ways I can think of, for example
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&2&0 \\ 0 &0&0&6 \\ 0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix} $$
Or maybe
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 
2&0&0&0 \\ 0&6&0&0 \\ 0&0 &0 &0 \\0 &0 &0 &0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Because both of them, when multiplied by 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x \\ x^2 \\ x^3 \end{bmatrix}
Will give the correct answer. Thus, what is the correct way to solve this?

Comment: I don't see how $F$ can be a map from $\mathbb{R}_3[x]\times\mathbb{R}_3[x]$ into itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you pick an ordered basis for the domain and co domain then the order is fixed.

Pick the basis $x\mapsto 1, x\mapsto x, x\mapsto x^2, x\mapsto x^3$.